# php_memcached.dll for windows

Tags: memcached

Where can I find a `php_memcached.dll` for PHP (NOTE THIS IS NOT the memcache extension this is the memcache**d** extension). I would love to take advantage of callbacks. I've checked WAMP and XAMP and http://downloads.php.net/pierre/ but have found nothing.

Comment: This link is useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693195/does-memcached-dll-exist

Comment: @secretlm php_memcache is different from php_memcached